# Poisson Distribution , intuitive misunderstanding

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

n: #trials $\quad$ p:P(success)  $\quad$   X:# success in n_trial

If each trial is independent , then distribution is Bin(n,p) . Here we are looking what $ i^th $ trial results in ? We can also answer questions like P(X = k)

Up until now , things were simple. If I plot at what time trial took plce from some start time , then spacing between 2 trials can be totally random on time axis (like taking 1 , resting for hour and then taking 2 back to back and so on ...)

Now , I can enquire about P(#success = k in time $t_0$). Here we can divide our time frame into finer and finer intervals to avoid overlap( >1 trials in an interval). $''This\quad description\quad leads\quad to\quad poisson \quad distribution ,\quad if\quad I\quad understood\quad correctly ''$

But I have certain arguments:::
In certain time interval, it is possible that no trial took place, leave away getting success. According to me-->$$ P(success \quad in \quad i^th slot)  = P(trial\quad in\quad i^th\quad slot ,\quad success\quad in\quad trial) = P(trial\quad in\quad i^th\quad slot )*p$$

$$ P(no\quad success \quad in \quad i^th slot) = P(no\quad trial\quad in\quad i^th\quad slot) + P(trial\quad in\quad i^th\quad slot , \quad no\quad success\quad in\quad trial)$$

Though both $ P(success \quad in \quad i^th slot)\quad and\quad P(no\quad success \quad in \quad i^th slot)\quad $ add to 1 but $ \quad P(trial\quad in\quad i^th\quad slot) \quad $
is HGeom distribution (not independent of previou (i-1) slots)

$$Please\quad help ,\quad also\quad shed\quad some\quad light\quad on\quad rate\quad parameter\quad (lambda) \quad in \quad Poisson\quad distribution $$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Instead of posting a new question, please edit your old question to improve it.